# How to suppress a join edge in chains when using foreach?

Tags: foreach, tikz-chains, join

How to remove/suppress the edge from node `3` to node `4` in the following code using `chains` and `join`?

Do I have to split the `foreach` into two smaller ones?

[image: chain]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta, chains}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.00cm, 
      every node/.style = {draw, circle, fill = blue!20},
      every join/.style = {->},
      start chain = path]

      \foreach \i in {1, ..., 7} {
        \node [on chain, join] {\i};
      }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta, chains}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.00cm,
      every node/.style = {draw, circle, fill = blue!20},
      every join/.style = {->},
      start chain = path]

      \foreach \i in {1, ..., 7} {
      \ifnum\i=4
        \node [on chain] {\i};
      \else
        \node [on chain, join] {\i};
      \fi
      }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta, chains}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.00cm,
      every node/.style = {draw, circle, fill = blue!20, on chain},
      every join/.style = {->},
      start chain = path]

      \foreach \i in {1, ..., 7} {
      \ifnum\i=4
        \node {\i};
      \else
        \node [join] {\i};
      \fi
      }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @hengxin, you are welcome! see updated answer.